# Passing a function as default argument in another function

Tags: c++11

How to pass a function as default argument to another function..

For example ...

If the question is.:
Write a program in c++ to print any message using display function and use another function namely input as default argument?

Comment: What have you tried doing and where is the problem?

Comment: So you've basically posted a question from your assignment and expect us to guess what your teacher meant? Nope, not gonna happen.

Comment: If I use something like display (input())      where input fuction is having the message .Is it possible?????

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You can use `std::function` and give it a default, as to be seen in the print function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

void bar() {
    std::cout << "bar\n";
}


void print(std::function<void()> f = bar) {
    f();
}

int main () {
    print();
    print(foo);
}
```

For the next question, please show what you did so far and ask from that start a concrete question.

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider closing it.